# How do I configure Windows 7 to get its timezone from DHCP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dhcp, time-zone

The DHCP protocol supports [setting the time zone](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4833) and the Windows DHCP Server [implements this feature](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/networking/lan/dhcp/microsoft/configuration.shtml).

The time zone on my company laptop (a member of a Windows domain) never changes when I connect to different networks in different time zones.

What do I need to configure on my client to allow it to acquire the time zone information from the DHCP server? Is the fact that I am on a domain preventing this from happening?

Comment: RFC4833 and Windows DHCP server seem to disaggree on how to send the timezone info to the client. With RFC4833 the server can sends a string like "Europe/Berlin", but [Windows DHCP Server](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/networking/lan/dhcp/microsoft/configuration.shtml) seems to send the info as a Time Offset - a number. I wouln't bother anyway: The usual DHCP "server" is a small linux router with ISC DHCPd or Dnsmasq.

Comment: TurboJ, I agree that is what I would use for my own DHCP server, however, the question is how to get windows to recognize the time zone.